# Multiple background images - background-position content - grid - CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, layout, background, frontend

I'm currently working on a landing page that requires a height of 100vh and incorporates 13 background images positioned differently on the page. I'm facing challenges in making the layout responsive and ensuring that it works well on both desktop and mobile devices.

Here's a brief overview of the requirements:

The landing page should have a height of 100vh.
There are 8 background images that need to be positioned differently on the page.
The mobile layout should exclude the left and right images, while the top and bottom images should be divided into three sections each.
I've tried using position: absolute and media queries to adjust the image positions, but the responsiveness seems off and confusing for users.
Additionally, I'm having trouble applying a border-radius with filter blur to the background images when I put the style on the div container of the page.
Here's the specific code snippet for the background-position property that I'm using:

```
backgroundPosition: `
  left top -80%,
  left bottom -80%,
  left calc(30% - 80px) center,
  left calc(15% - 80px) center,
  center top -80%,
  center bottom -80%,
  right top  -80%,
  right bottom  -80%,
  right calc(30% - 80px) center,
  right calc(15% - 80px) center
`,
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice, tips, or suggestions on how to effectively handle this situation and create a better responsive layout for the landing page. I'm open to alternative approaches or techniques that can help me achieve the desired result without compromising user experience.

Thank you in advance for your help!

[codepen](https://codepen.io/ledthepug/pen/jOQWebe)

Update:
Unfortunately, I haven't been able to receive assistance here lately. It seems that Stack Overflow is not as reliable as it used to be for seeking help. Nonetheless, I managed to tackle the issue on my own by utilizing the Grid system, specifically by employing properties like grid-template-columns, grid-template-rows, and grid-area. To achieve the desired outcome, I utilized the images as a background within the respective divs.

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and also explain what is meant by the left and right images which are not to appear on narrower viewports.

Comment: Hi @AHaworth left-right images are the left and right images lol you can check the layout that shows the images, thanks for the help...

Comment: I’m pleased you have solved your problem but I am a bit concerned about your complaint that you had had no help from SO. I was following your question and waiting to see the code you had already which never appeared. It’s worth reading the link I gave 5 days ago if you want help!